# Warning 665: Unparenthesized parameter 2 in macro 'SET_RECORD' is passed an expression

Tags: c++, lint

This is a part of my code base ...
As it is confusing to indent/group the variable in MACRO calling to avoid the lint warning
code :

```
 enum baseId{
    ADDRESS_ID = 0,
    ML_ID
    };
 struct strAddress{
        uint8   Address[6];
    };
 struct strCam{
        FLOAT         currXmm;
        FLOAT         currYmm;
    };
#define SET_RECORD(recordid, bufferptr, type)     {               \
RecordReturnType           status;                        \
RecordManager<type> sampleRecord;                     \
validate(bufferptr != NULL);                          \
status = sampleRecord.SetRecord(recordid, *(type *) (const_cast<void *>(bufferptr))\
         );                           \
validate(status == E_OK);                         \
}

bool fun(const uint8 *diagData){
    bool ret ;
    strAddress tempMac;
    memcpy(tempMac.Address, diagData,sizeof(strAddress));
    SET_RECORD((uint32)ADDRESS_ID,(const void *) &tempMac,strAddress); //line
        ret = TRUE;             
    }

Warning 665: Unparenthesized parameter 2 in macro 'SET_RECORD' is passed an expression
```

Comment //Line is the place caz of this the warning arises ...I tried in different way by making bracket to the second variable but still warning persist...

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, Lint warns you about the 4th line of your macro, `validate(bufferptr != NULL);`. If the `bufferptr` is bound to an expression which contains operators of lesser precedence than `!=`, the macro will expand to something you might not expect:

`SET_RECORD(x, condition ? thisbuf : thatbuf, y)` expands into: `validate(condition ? thisbuf : thatbuf != NULL);` which means `validate(condition ? thisbuf : (thatbuf != NULL));`.

Rewrite the line thus: `validate((bufferptr) != NULL);`.

Answer (score 0):

Surround your macro parameters by parenthesizes every times you use them inside your macro to avoid such problem: https://servicios.excentia.es/sonar-demo/rules/show/pclint:665?layout=true